# jQuery tokenInput search result is at the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-tokeninput

`enter code here`
I'm having this some sort of problem in jQuery Tokeninput.

It seems that the search result is at the bottom of the page. I don't know what really is the problem here. It seems like it's a CSS issue.

I made a video showing what the problem is.

http://screencast.com/t/oez0zd4mNz

Here's my jsfiddle code:

http://jsfiddle.net/NPfGC/

it works there but on my site it is not working, the search result is at the bottom.

I made a page on my site for you to see: http://discovrd.com/weird

Any thoughts on this? Your idea would be greatly appreciated and rewarded!

Comment: We need to see the relevant parts of your code (possibly on jsfiddle.net) to help you.

Comment: @ExplosionPills: here's my code: http://pastebin.com/0uiR2K8c

Comment: @ExplosionPills Here's my jsfiddle.net code http://jsfiddle.net/NPfGC/ it works from there but in my site, the search result is at the bottom

Comment: @ExplosionPills Here's the url of my site: http://discovrd.com/weird

Answer (score 0):

I already solved this one.

I am using `jquery-1.8.3.min.js` on my site, then I changed it into `jquery-1.7.1.min.js` then it solved the bug. I am not sure if `jquery-1.8.3.min.js` is a buggy script but I guess changing it solved my problem. The solution is kinda weird but it works.

Thanks!